# If Christopher Columbus hadn't reached the Americas, when would they have been (re)discovered, with wide, international trade networks?

Tags: alternate-history

To my understanding, Christopher Columbus's plan to sail around the world and reach Asia was widely considered a doomed journey (not because most educated people thought the earth was flat, but because the distances involved would have been too vast, and nobody knew about the Americas at the time.)

Columbus's voyage was only funded because the king and queen of Spain were so excited about crusading that they figured they might as well.

Once Columbus reported back about the Americas (and his genocide campaign, which isn't strictly relevant to this discussion), the general public became aware of the new world, and additional explorers went out to find it.

---

Suppose for a moment that Isabella and Ferdinand chose not to fund Columbus's voyage. How long would this have delayed the discovery of the Americas? How different would the Americas (and Europe) be when the discovery was made?

Strictly speaking, the rediscovery of the Americas would always likely be a chance event, but I would like to know at what point such a chance event would become a near certainty. Perhaps the question is better expressed as "had Columbus not been funded, at what point in history would it be extremely unlikely that the Americas had not been discovered?"

---

Note: I am specifically talking about a large-scale interaction between the old and new world. This doesn't necessarily mean colonization, but it does mean that any commoner on the street would know that the Americas existed, and that regular trade ships would travel between the Americas and Europe.

Note 2: I understand that Lief Ericson and crew founded Vinland in the Americas back in the day. However, Vinland died out and was forgotten. Any answers that start before columbus's voyage aren't relevant to this discussion.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131536/discussion-on-question-by-globin347-if-christopher-columbus-hadnt-reached-the-a).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [book "Before 1492"](https://portuguese-american-journal.com/book-before-1492-the-portuguese-discovery-of-america-editors-note/) lays out a case that the Portuguese were already exploring South America a decade before Columbus returned to Spain.  That's why they didn't want to sponsor his voyage; they already knew about the Americas and wanted to keep them secret.

Whether or not this theory turns out to be true, the evidence for it suggests that the European exploration of the Americas wasn't "a chance event" per your question, but in fact an inevitable result of the combination of new sailing technology and global trade motivations.  That is: the money was there and the tech was there, someone was gonna do it.

Given this, I'd suggest that someone else would have made a high-profile exploration of the Americas within 20 years of Columbus not sailing, with a significant probability that it would have been within 5 years (Cabot's voyage was in 1497).  I'd further argue that if it was more on the 20 years end of the scale, that would have been because the explorers decided to keep their find secret for several years.

The alt-Columbus could have been:

- The Portuguese, also looking for a route to India, whether Dias or another explorer;
- The Basques, selling information on "islands near their secret cod fishing grounds";
- Cabot or another English-funded explorer, following up rumors of new lands discovered by the Vikings or the Celts;
- Even someone else funded by the Spanish Crown, since they clearly had the money for it, a desire to compete with Portugal; most likely this would be [Amerigo Vespucci](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amerigo_Vespucci), who was looking for exploration money at the same time that Columbus was.

It's unlikely that Skandanavians would have sent anyone, as the 15th century was still deep in the Little Ice Age.  And the Venetians and Genoese had too much of an investment in Eastern trade routes to fund an expedition.

Comment: It would be sick if the guy "discovering" America was actually named Amerigo !

Comment: And if it was named after him; Vespucchia!

Comment: The idea that they sailed East to find a shorter route to India is pure bunk. It is absolutely ridiculous. They knew that China was in the way, that they would have to sail below the Vietnam peninsula, and it would be a LONGER route. Anything else is just calling them 'stupid' and 'ignorant'. They were intelligent. world-aware, and knowledgeable about the globe. Columbus would not have sailed so far North unless he was specifically looking for the continent he knew would be there. Believing anything else is just wearing a tin foil hat.

Comment: It was a race between the Portuguese and the rest of Europe to colonize the lands in the continent they all new existed above South America. As has been mentioned, the distance between the Eastern hump of Africa and the western coast of Brazil is a hop skip and a jump, easily doable and they knew the navigation by the stars. They wanted the continent north of Brazil

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond, they were looking for a route to the *Indies*, not *India*. The Indies, in their minds, included what is today Malaysia, Indonesia, the Philippines and other parts of Southeast Asia. China wasn't "in the way", China was one of the destinations he was specifically aiming for as it was part of the Spice Trade. Everything you've said is based on that mistake.

Comment: @Keith Morrison
 Ummm, check a map. There was nothing in the 'Indies' that was significant, the real trade was with India and China. China by overland, not by ship. They knew how far China would be, going around the globe. They knew how far the 'Indies' would be, going around the globe. They knew there was another continent in the way. It makes no sense except as an attempt to make a revisionist history work..

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond, try looking at actual history and not just a map. The reason the Portuguese pushed the route around Africa was specifically to avoid needing the overland and Red Sea routes to both India, China, and the other sources of commodities, which was controlled by the other powers such as the Ottomans. Not to mention we have documents from the time stating Columbus's reasoning (and the reasons people rejected it), as well as John Cabot's. You're the one engaging in revisionist conspiracy theory.

Comment: @
Keith Morrison
 So, about Ford 'inventing; the assembly line. LOTS of documentation on that, even from Ford itself. Doesn't make it true.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond As for the hop-skip-and-a-jump bit, the closest distance between the African and the south American continent is about 2700 km, which can be shaved town to 2500 if you start from Cape Verde. The distance from the west coast of Ireland to Newfoundland is just over 3000 km. It's longer, sure, but not dramatically so.

Comment: @
EdvinW
 However, if the prevailing currents (and they knew of them) are taken into consideration, distances change. The goal was to colonize the new lands, not to find a better route to the Indies, India, or China.  There was an accurate globe in the halls of the royalty, it is in museums. It included some representation of the 'New Lands'. One brief glance at it would demonstrate to them how FAR these lands would be by sailing to the west.  Any attempt to suggest any other version of history is ludicrous. You might want to consult the Avalon project instead of Fox News.

Comment: "The earliest globe that survives today was made in 1492 by Martin Behaim, a German navigator and geographer in the employ of King João II of Portugal. Behaim's globe recorded not only the lie of the lands being discovered by seabourne explorers, but also details of overseas commodities, market places and local trading protocols. Thus, the earliest surviving globe, which probably reflects many others produced around the same time, features information on more than cartography." https://www.whipplemuseum.cam.ac.uk/explore-whipple-collections/globes/brief-history-globes When Columbus set sail.

Answer (score 13):

Based on some references it's suspected that Basque and English fisherman were aware of the Grand Banks of Newfoundland in the period before Columbus. There's no evidence (yet) that they actually landed, but it's not an impossibility to think it would have been inevitable. In any event, Zuan Chabotto (John Cabot) sailed an exploratory mission on behalf of the English Crown in 1497 and reached North America. What's important is that the mission was *not* an exploratory expedition looking to extend Columbus's voyage. Cabot was also seeking a sea route to the East Indies, but on a more northerly latitude, since the distance around the globe at a higher latitude was less.

Of additional importance was from where he sailed: since 1480, ships from Bristol had been seeking the legendary island of Hy-Brazil, which Celtic myth said was somewhere in the Atlantic, and merchants in the city believed ships from Bristol had made it there in the past but the location had been lost. Also of note was that while Vinland may have been lost, *Greenland* certainly wasn't. The last Norse settlements had died out only a few decades before, and people knew where it was.

The combination of these things make it pretty much inevitable that English-based ships would have reached the Americas, if they hadn't already, not much later than they really did.

Answer (score 10):

**Bart!**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bartolomeu_Dias

[image: bart]

Bartolomeu Dias was a serious, serious navigator and explorer.  He was sponsored by the Portuguese and went all over the world.

> After Diogo Cão's second voyage failed to reach the end of the African
> coastline, King John II remained determined to continue the effort. In
> October, 1486, he commissioned Dias to lead an expedition in search of
> a trade route around the southern tip of Africa...The Dias expedition
> had explored an additional thousand miles of African coastline,
> ultimately rounded the southern tip of the continent and demonstrated
> that the most effective southward course lay in the open ocean well to
> west of Africa - a route that would be followed by generations of
> Portuguese sailors....
>
> It was not until 1498 that another voyage was commissioned and Dias
> was asked provide assistance.[17] Using his experience with maritime
> exploration, Dias contributed to the design and construction of the
> São Gabriel and its sister ship the São Rafael. These were two of the
> ships used in 1498 by Vasco da Gama to sail around the Cape of Good
> Hope and continue to India. Dias participated in the first leg of da
> Gama's voyage but stayed behind after reaching the Cape Verde
> Islands.[18]
>
> Two years later he was one of the captains of the second Indian
> expedition, headed by Pedro Álvares Cabral. This flotilla was the
> first to reach Brazil, landing there on 22 April 1500, and then
> continuing east to India...

Not only was Dias the first to go around the tip of Africa he discovered Brazil, then died trying to go around South America on the way to India.  Dude was the real deal and no-one made fun of him for going around in a skirt.

Given a guy like this on hand as well as other activities of the Portuguese that were contemporaneous with those of Columbus, Portuguese explorers would have found the New World within a couple of decades of 1492 - probably via the aforementioned crossing from Africa to Cape Verde to Brazil.

Comment: You may want to explain *why* the second Indian expedition hit the coast of Brazil. This would make it clear that it would have stumbled on Brazil iin 1500 regardless of whether Columbus had reported back from the Antilles in 1492 or not.

Comment: Please add it on @AlexP!  I do not know the story.  I could look it up but you have a prose gift, and  I like the way you write history.

Comment: Oh, it is not a story. It was forced by geography and how the trade winds blow. A sailing ship [going from Iberia to the Cape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vasco_da_Gama#/media/File:Map_of_Portuguese_Carreira_da_India.gif) sails south-west with the trade winds, and continues until it crosses the Equator and intercepts the westerly winds, then turns south-east. The turning point is necessarily not far from the coast of Brazil. If Bartolomeu Dias hadn't found Brazil then the next trade expedition would have.... It's inescapable once the trade route to India around the Cape was established.

Answer (score 2):

As people are mentioning, yes, people from the old world visited the new world before Columbus. Not just the Vikings, but it is technically possible there were some more ancient, and also possible some people even a few decades before Columbus to my knowledge.

That aside, Columbus did not exist in a vacuum. In the 18th and 19th centuries, to my knowledge, a lot of mythos was created about Columbus, stuff like that he was the first person to propose that the Earth was round. Beyond the fact that most educated people believed already in that, there was a great deal of exploration going on in that time, aided by notable improvements in tech.

I am certain that if it hadn't been Columbus, it would've been someone else, maybe even not more than a decade later. It would have perhaps though been a wholly different country and circumstance of discovery. I'm sure you can find some alternate history videos or posts online about it.

Answer (score 0):

In the 1400s or 1500s. There was lots of exploring going around in the time as well as advances in ship technology. There were other big explorers. Most of all though was there were kingdoms who would fund them. Eventually we probably would see someone else who would have the same idea as Columbus or ship technology would be advanced enough where Europeans would be confident they could reach Asia by sailing there directly.

Answer (score 0):

While we are doing alternate history,  how about this alternative?

What if the Chinese exploration of the new world in 1421 had not been lost?  What if China had proceeded to colonize what we call America had establish trade routes across the Pacific?

[https://www.amazon.com/1421-Year-China-Discovered-America/dp/0061564893](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0061564893)

Comment: China is and never was a 'colonizing, imperialistic' nation. (The Mongols were not Hahn Chinese). Therefore, the question should be 'suppose the white West were as pacifist and non-aggressive as the Chinese?' The Chinese culture/civilization lasted over 8,000 years as a continuous contiguous society. North America would now be populated by the original indigenous populations, not the 'conquerors'. Colonializing imperialistic nations have always failed, after devastating the original indigenous populations. An interesting thought. Was 'colonization' REALLY a good thing?

Answer (score -1):

Frame challenge.

Christopher Columbus did not decide on his own to set sail, he was commissioned to set sail. He was sent with one particular purpose - to claim sovereignty over the land that they KNEW was there. Europeans had globes with an unknown land mass where North America is. If he had not been successful, there would be a host of immediate followers sent out by the various royalty of the countries at the time. it was a race to find and claim this land mass, not a whim of some particular sailor.
This is made very evident in [the original charter](https://avalon.law.yale.edu/15th_century/colum.asp) that was issued to Chris Columbus.

> FERDINAND and ELIZABETH, by the Grace of God, King and Queen of
> Castile, of Leon, of Arragon, of Sicily, of Granada, of Toledo, of
> Valencia, of Galicia, of Majorca, of Minorca, of Sevil, of Sardinia,
> of Jaen, of Algarve, of Algezira, of Gibraltar, of the Canary Islands,
> Count and Countess of Barcelona, Lord and Lady of Biscay and Molina,
> Duke and Duchess of Athens and Neopatria. Count and Countess of
> Rousillion and Cerdaigne, Marquess and Marchioness of Oristan and
> Gociano, &c.
>
> For as much of you, Christopher Columbus, are going by our command,
> with some of our vessels and men, to discover and subdue some Islands
> and Continent in the ocean, and it is hoped that by God's assistance,
> some of the said Islands and Continent in the ocean will be discovered
> and conquered by your means and conduct, therefore it is but just and
> reasonable, that since you expose yourself to such danger to serve us,
> you should be rewarded for it. And we being willing to honour and
> favour You for the reasons aforesaid: Our will is, That you,
> Christopher Columbus, after discovering and conquering the said
> Islands and Continent in the said ocean, or any of them, shall be our
> Admiral of the said Islands and Continent you shall so discover and
> conquer; and that you be our Admiral, Vice-Roy, and Governour in them,
> and that for the future, you may call and stile yourself, D.
> Christopher Columbus, and that your sons and successors in the said
> employment, may call themselves Dons, Admirals, Vice-Roys, and
> Governours of them; and that you may exercise the office of Admiral,
> with the charge of Vice-Roy and Governour of the said Islands and
> Continent, which you and your Lieutenants shall conquer, and freely
> decide all causes, civil and criminal, appertaining to the said
> employment of Admiral, Vice-Roy, and Governour, as you shall think fit
> in justice, and as the Admirals of our kingdoms use to do; and that
> you have power to punish offenders; and you and your Lieutenants
> exercise the employments of Admiral, Vice-Roy, and Governour, in all
> things belonging to the said offices, or any of them; and that you
> enjoy the perquisites and salaries belonging to the said employments,
> and to each of them, in the same manner as the High Admiral of our
> kingdoms does. And by this our letter, or a copy of it signed by a
> Public Notary: We command Prince John, our most dearly beloved Son,
> the Infants, Dukes, Prelates, Marquesses, Great Masters and Military
> Orders, Priors. Commendaries, our Counsellors, Judges, and other
> Officers of Justice whatsoever, belonging Courts, and Chancery, and
> Constables of Castles, Strong Houses, and others; and all
> Corporations, Bayliffs, Governours, Judges, Commanders, Sea Officers;
> and the Aldermen, Common Council, Officers, and Good People of all
> Cities, Lands, and Places in our Kingdoms and Dominions, and in those
> you shall conquer and subdue, and the captains masters, mates, and
> other officers and sailors, our natural subjects now being, or that
> shall be for the time to come, and any of them that when you shall
> have discovered the said Islands and Continent in the ocean; and you,
> or any that shall have your commission, shall have taken the usual
> oath in such cases, that they for the future, look upon you as long as
> you live, and after you, your son and heir, and so from one heir to
> another forever, as our Admiral on our said Ocean, and as Vice-Roy and
> Governour of the said Islands and Continent, by you, Christopher
> Columbus, discovered and conquered; and that they treat you and your
> Lieutenants, by you appointed, for executing the employments of
> Admiral, Vice-Roy, and Governour, as such in all respects, and give
> you all the perquisites and other things belonging and appertaining to
> the said offices; and allow, and cause to be allowed you, all the
> honours, graces, concessions, prehaminences, prerogatives, immunities,
> and other things, or any of them which are due to you, by virtue of
> your commands of Admiral, Vice-Roy, and Governour, and to be observed
> completely, so that nothing be diminished; and that they make no
> objection to this, or any part of it, nor suffer it to be made;
> forasmuch as we from this time forward, by this our letter, bestow on
> you the employments of Admiral, Vice-Roy, and perpetual Governour
> forever; and we put you into possession of the said offices, and of
> every of them, and full power to use and exercise them, and to receive
> the perquisites and salaries belonging to them, or any of them, as was
> said above. Concerning all which things, if it be requisite, and you
> shall desire it, We command our Chancellour, Notaries, and other
> Officers, to pass, seal, and deliver to you, our Letter of Privilege,
> in such form and legal manner, as you shall require or stand in need
> of. And that none of them presume to do any thing to the contrary,
> upon pain of our displeasure, and forfeiture of 30 ducats for each
> offence. And we command him, who shall show them this our Letter, that
> he summon them to appear before us at our Court, where we shall then
> be, within fifteen days after such summons, under the said penalty.
> Under which same, we also command any Public Notary whatsoever, that
> he give to him that shows it him, a certificate under his seal, that
> we may know how our command is obeyed.
>
> GIVEN at Granada, on the 30th of April, in the year of our Lord,
> 1492.-

They knew a LOT more than revisionist North American history gives them credit for. It is strange what weird conspiracy theories North Americans are taught as 'the truth' in their school system and mass media, even though the truth is documented within their own University archives. The Europeans knew there was a continent in the way, they knew it was unclaimed, they knew it was potentially very profitable, and they knew it was perfect for imperialist colonization.

They were definitely NOT flat-earthers. They knew within a very slim margin of error what the diameter of the Earth was, they knew where Asia was in relation to that globe, and they knew how to navigate on the 'far side' of the Earth using the sky. That is, they knew what the sky would look like all around this globe.

Discovering the Continent was NOT an 'accident'. It was deliberate, directed, exploration with the intent to 'conquer and subjugate'. The Europeans were determined to navigate to it, whether Chris did it or someone else did.

Comment: Columbus was sent out to conquer "The Indies" (now known as southeast Asia).  The reason why Columbus had trouble getting funding was that the mainstream view was that Asia was 12000 miles west of the Canary Islands (much further than a ship of the time could sail between landfalls), while Columbus thought it was 2400 miles (right at the edge of possibility).

Comment: @Mark
 With only a few ships Columbus was going to conquer all of India? Columbus did not seek funding, funding sought HIM. He was picked to go, out of several rivals. Americans do like their conspiracy theories.

Comment: @L.Dutch I will let the editing go, but if you notice the capitalization, it as an attempt at a pun - the NEW lands that they KNEW were there. The discovery of "America' was not new news to the Europeans.

Comment: Columbus sailed far too far North to be headed for the Indies. He KNEW where he was going. He landed exactly where he thought he would, on exactly the same continent he thought he would. Believing anything else is pure populist historical revisionism. Do you still believe the 'War of the Worlds' radio broadcast caused hysterical panic in North American cities?

Comment: It was me who did the editing. StackExchange is intended for all kind of users ; some of them (myself included) may not understand the pun unless explicitly explained.

Comment: @breversa
 Sorry, I saw the 'edited by' as L.Dutch, your reference did not show up.